# Filtering ObjectListView - Python

Tags: python, filter, wxpython, objectlistview, sniffer

I'm using ObjectListView and I want to know if I can filter it by it's attributes. I'm using scapy to build a sniffer so I show all the packets in an ObjectListView, each row is a PacketObject that has an attribute called **packet**. Let's say I want to Filter by TCP, so I need the **packet** of the objects to contain TCP. I saw a way to filter by the information that is shown on the ObjectListView but I need to filter by attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjectListView has filtering built-in to the widget:

- http://objectlistview-python-edition.readthedocs.org/en/latest/features.html?highlight=filter#filtering

You do have to set up the filter yourself. You can get some ideas by looking at the C++ docs for the widget as they actually have some filtering examples:

- http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/filtering.html